# Best way to handle apostrophes when searching a MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, special-characters, collation

I am currently using

```
MATCH column_name AGAINST ( 'search_term' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

where `column_name` is full text indexed. This works for the majority of cases but if the user searches for `"items"` I would like it to return both `"short string items"` AND `"short string item's"` from the DB (assuming both exist).  Currently the way it is searching it treats the apostrophe as a letter rather than a word break such as a space.  I saw some suggestions that I create another column of basically search friendly terms, in which case I could strip out the apostrophes but I was wondering if there was a better way, such as adjusting the collation to treat the apostrophe differently?

Comment: Does `column_name` contain large blocks of text that you're searching, or just single words?

Comment: @Barmar think of the data like movie titles, so fairly short strings.

Comment: But not single words, so the deleted `SOUNDEX()` answer wouldn't work.

Comment: @Barmar correct, that was my lack of explanation.  I modified the post to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I ended up implementing first searches the fulltext indexed column in natural language mode and then also searches the column with a REPLACE and LIKE search:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
WHERE
    MATCH column_name AGAINST ("search_term" IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
    OR REPLACE (column_name, "'", "") LIKE "%search_term%";
```

This seems to return the proper results I am looking for.

For example if user searches for `"items"`, `"item's"`, `"string items"`, or `"string items"` it should return both `"short string item's"` and `"short string items"` (again assuming the exist in the DB).